# postgresql: Accidentally i upgraded the package. How to restore the old data

Tags: postgresql

I am using archlinux. I didnt have much idea of pre postgresql upgrade related things.

I just upgraded the postgresql package from 9.x to 10.0 using pacman.

Now i cant open my databases.

Now is there any way i can restore my databases back which i have created.

Comment: Have you tried rolling back to 9.x ? What errors do you see in DBs log ?

Comment: No i didnt tried to roll back.

Comment: The "x" in 9.x is relevant. Reinstall the correct version of PostgreSQL, and your database should work fine.

Comment: Ok i will try it

Comment: If you still have the old binaries (or are able to install them in a different directory), you could use `pg_upgrade` to migrate the data.